# Do "enter the battlefield" abilities trigger heroic? Do creatures that leave and reenter the battlefield trigger again?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

So, here's the play:

Player 1 has [Staunch-Hearted Warrior](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Staunch-Hearted%20Warrior) on the field. They play [Living Totem](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Living%20Totem) and target the warrior, giving the warrior a +1/1 counter.

Question 1: Would Living Totem's ability trigger Staunch-Hearted Warrior's heroic ability?

Back to the game now. Next turn, player 1 plays [Invasive Species](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Invasive%20Species) and returns Living Totem to their hand. On the following turn, they play Living Totem back onto the battlefield.
Would Living Totem's ability trigger again?

Comment: In the future, I think you should ask one question per, erm, question. This makes it possible to identify duplicates. It also makes your question easier to search for, both here and on Google.

Answer (score 3):

Question 1: No.

Creature spells (such as [Living Totem](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Living%20Totem)) don't target. When you cast Living Totem, you do not pick any targets. Once it eventually resolves, it's ability triggers and you choose targets when you place it on the stack. But placing an ability on the stack is not casting a spell, so it doesn't trigger [Staunch-Hearted Warrior](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Staunch-Hearted%20Warrior)'s ability.

Aura spells, on the other hand, always target. Casting [Messenger's Speed](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Messenger%27s%20Speed) targeting Staunch-Hearted Warrior would trigger the latter's ability.

Question 2: Yes.

Living Totem was in your hand (not on the battlefield) one moment and on the battlefield the next, so it entered the battlefield. As such, it's ETB ability triggered.

Comment: For #2, probably worth mentioning the whole "new object" thing, since he seemed to think that Living Totem would remember that it had previously entered the battlefield.

Comment: @GendoIkari, I purposefully omitted the following since I considered it irrelevant and confusing, but since you ask for it: *Technically, "Living Totem's ability triggers again" is incorrect. It's a brand new object with no relation to the one that previously existed on the battlefield or in your hand[CR 400.7], so "The new Living Totem's ability triggers" would be more accurate.*

Answer (score 1):

No.

Living totems has a triggered ability that adds +1/+1 counters, which triggers upon him entering the battlefield. That is not the same thing as 'casting a spell that targets Staunch-Hearted warrior', so the Staunch-Hearted Warrior's heroic ability will not trigger.

However, if you target the Staunch-Hearted Warrior with an enchantment, then bounced it, and then recast it, it would trigger the Staunch-Hearted Warrior's heroic ability twice.